# Rails 3.2.8 - How to receive image, video and sound file without form on Rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, image, carrierwave

I'm making an API that deals with mobile devices interactions.

I know how to deal with simple variables handling such as this:

```
curl -XPOST -H "Content-Type: application/json" "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/registrations" -d "{registration: {"nickname":"john_doe", "password":"secret", "confirmed":"true", "email":"john.doe@gmail.com","blood_type":"B+"}}"
```

This POST call will go to my controller:

```
class RegistrationController < ApplicationController
    def create
      Registration.create!(params[:registration])
    end
end
```

It's just a very simple way to post information to my Registration model.

However, if I'm handling image, sound and video upload using a JSON through a POST request, besides having to use an uploaded like Carrierwave, is there anything else I need to do?

For example, would it work a request like this?

```
curl -XPOST -H "Content-Type: application/json" "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/registrations" -d "{registration: {"nickname":"john_doe", "password":"secret", "confirmed":"true", "email":"john.doe@gmail.com","blood_type":"B+", "image": IMAGE_FILE_IN_BINARY_OR_SOME_OTHER_FORMAT?}}"
```

Should the image file be trasmitted as a binary or there's a specific format for it?